# PostgreSQL What's the difference between NOW() - INTERVAL and its value

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am working with PostgreSQL 12.6 and TimescaleDB.

I have an hypertable `raws` which contains a field `"time"` of type `timestamp without time zone NOT NULL`.

Now I have 2 queries:

```
select * from raws where time > NOW() - INTERVAL '15 day';
```

This one gives me this:

```
2021-04-08 00:00:00
2021-04-08 00:10:00
2021-04-08 00:20:00
```

And NOW() is equal to: `2021-04-20 16:48:41.575584+02`

But now, if I take the value of `NOW() - INTERVAL '15 day'` which is, at this time `2021-04-05 16:48:41.575584+02`, and put it my query like this:

```
select * from raws where time > '2021-04-05 16:48:41.575584+02';
```

It doesn't work anymore: I get 0 results, but no errors.

So what is it that makes the second query fail?

Is it something wrong with TimescaleDB or PostgreSQL, or am I missing something with formats?

Comment: Please provide some example data for the "time" values returned for the first  query, as well as the value of `now()` for the query. Add this data to your question.

Comment: I updated the post, I hope this is clearer !

Comment: I don't believe that. Please come up with a reproducible example.

Comment: A couple of observations 1) `2021-04-20 16:48:41.575584+02 - interval '15 days'` would return `2021-04-05 16:48:41.575584+02` not `2021-04-05 15:44:10.023066+02`. This is would materially affect this result. 2) Your returned values are `2021-04-08 00:00:00, 28894786`, note the ',' decimal separator vs your other values having XXXX.xxxx. Is this just a cut/paste issue or are you dealing with different locales? 3) I cannot replicate on a stock 12.5 instance of Postgres.

Comment: 1) I forgot to change it, but yes it does return `2021-04-05 16:48:41.575584+02`
2) The comma separates the two values I got in `raws`, sorry if it was unclear
3) I'm going to try with a stock instance too, if I can't replicate it either, would this be an issue with TimescaleDB ?

Comment: It's possible, but unlikely, if you can create a reproducible case where this is happening please do file a bug report. But most likely this is some sort of time zone issue, as you have a timestamp without timezone as your partitioning key, can you cast the result to a timestamp without timezone and see if that changes anything?

Comment: It does not really look like a TimescaleDB issue, it looks more like a type conversion issue.

Comment: I tried it with a similar table and I get the same result for both queries. Could you update the question with the full table definition and data that can reproduce the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to reproduce that bug on a fresh database, and everything worked fine.

The query `select * from raws where time > '2021-04-05 16:48:41.575584+02';` stops working when I import all my datas from a dump, so even though I don't know exactly what, there is a problem with that dump.